# gRPCCertificates.bundle: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

After adding `Firebase Core` using `Pods`, and building the project from the workspace, I get the following error, any ideas?

```
CpResource /Users/macbookpro2018/sites/ejected-calendar/ios/gRPCCertificates.bundle /Users/macbookpro2018/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rgcalendar-bfjzhbiwxklgqmchjhbjlpniuqst/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/rgcalendar.app/gRPCCertificates.bundle (in target: rgcalendar)
    cd /Users/macbookpro2018/sites/ejected-calendar/ios
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -strip-debug-symbols -strip-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/macbookpro2018/sites/ejected-calendar/ios/gRPCCertificates.bundle /Users/macbookpro2018/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rgcalendar-bfjzhbiwxklgqmchjhbjlpniuqst/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/rgcalendar.app

error: /Users/macbookpro2018/sites/ejected-calendar/ios/gRPCCertificates.bundle: No such file or directory


error: /Users/macbookpro2018/sites/ejected-calendar/ios/gRPCCertificates.bundle: No such file or directory
```

**Podfile**:

```
target 'rgcalendar' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for rgcalendar

 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the version specifier on `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'`

There were some related fixes months ago and 5.12.0 was released last November.

Comment: Done that, cleaned and rebuilt, but still get the error - do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Isolate the difference between your app and a sample app. Perhaps something in your app's Build Settings is causing a problem. More at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2898